# Semantics ui elements not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, semantic-ui

**HTML :**

```
 <div id="tabNewAutomaticPurchaseOrder" class="tTab">
        <div class="ui form stackable two column grid ">
            <div class="seven wide column">

                <h3 id="lblPurchaseDetailsAutomatictab" class="ui top attached tiny header">Bestillingsdetaljer</h3>
                <div class="ui attached segment">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrderNumberAutomatictab" class="inHeaderTextField1" Text="Serienr. Bestilling:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" class="inHeaderTextField2" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrderDateAutomatictab" class="inHeaderTextField3" Text="Bestillingsdato:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label13" class="inHeaderTextField4" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <label class="inHeaderCheckbox">
                        Vis/Lukk
                            <button id="btnViewDetailsNEWPO2" class="ui btn mini">
                                <i class="caret down icon"></i>
                            </button>
                    </label>
                    <div class="itemadd-container">
                        <div class="fields">
                            <div class="three wide field">

                                <div id="lblSupplierNameAutomatictab" class="ui blue horizontal label">Leverandør</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="three wide field">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxSupplierNameAutomatictab" runat="server" data-submit="SAVE_SUPPLIER_ITEM" meta:resourcekey="txtTechMakeResource1"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="two wide field">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxSupplierIdAutomatictab" runat="server" Enabled="false" ForeColor="Red"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="fields">
                         <div class="three wide field">                          
                             <div id="lblOrdertypeAutomatictab" class="ui blue horizontal label">Ordretype</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="three wide field">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="dropdowns" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="ddlordertypeFormResource1">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Selected="true"/>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="RE" Value="RE" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="LO" Value="LO"/>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="two wide field">
                                <input type="button" id="Button1" runat="server" class="ui btn mini" value="+" />
                         </div>
                        </div>

                    <div class="fields">
                        <div class="three wide field">
                            <label id="Label16" runat="server">Forsendelsesmåte</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="three wide field">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" CssClass="dropdowns" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="ddlordertypeFormResource1">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Tog" Value="66" Selected="true"/>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Bil" Value="67" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Hente selv" Value="68"/>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        </div>


                   <div class="fields">

                        <div class="two wide field">
                            <label id="Label17" runat="server">Forventet ankomst</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="two wide field">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" CssClass="NEWpodatepicker" runat="server" data-submit="SAVE_SUPPLIER_ITEM" meta:resourcekey="txtTechMakeResource1" ForeColor="Red" Enabled="false" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>


                        </div>

                </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

It seems like I do something wrong here:

**Todo :**

- Don't want the textbox to overlap the label.
- How can I avoid this? I thought that using fields and specifying
  their length would do the trick, apparently not.
- How can I make this responsive so that if the window gets shrinked, the textbox will NOT overlap the label?

**Problem Gif :**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use meta tag in header if you are using  html5 and avoid fixed positions in css

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"

This will set the viewport of your page, which will give the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: seems more of a comment.